# Layout measurement override of element should not return NaN values as its DesiredSize

Tags: .net, wpf, printing

I've run into a similar issue when I try to call `Measure` and pass the dynamically calculated size to that method:

> Layout measurement override of element 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' should not return NaN values as its DesiredSize.

I am trying to create a StackPanel on the fly and print it. Here's my code:

```
StackPanel printPanel = new StackPanel();

PrintableArea.Children.Remove(ChartBorder);
printPanel.Children.Add(ChartBorder);

//Get selected printer capabilities
System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = dialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(dialog.PrintTicket);

//Get scale of the print wrt to screen of visual
double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / printPanel.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight / printPanel.ActualHeight);

//Transform the Visual to scale
printPanel.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

//Get the size of the printer page
Size sz = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

//Update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
printPanel.Measure(sz);
printPanel.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

dialog.PrintVisual(printPanel, "Test");
```

Any clue what could be the cause of this? And the strange thing is this happens only with `StackPanel`. If I try to create a simple `TextBlock` for testing purpose and try to print that, everything works fine with no errors. I was wondering what's different when we call `Measure` for `StackPanel`?

Any help to fix this issue would be really great!

Answer (score 3):

Your are probably passing in Size(double.NaN, double.NaN) to the Measure call, which is bad. Your printPanel.ActualWidth/ActualHeight should be 0.0, which results in NaN. This is how Double defines NaN:

```
   public const double NaN = (double) 0.0 / (double) 0.0;
```

So you would need to pass in Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity) to get the desired size. After you arrange the printPanel, the ActualWidth/ActualHeight should be valid.

Comment: thanks for your response. After researching I figured that I need to set the MinHeight, MinWidth, MaxHeight and MaxWidth. Once I did that my printPanel got its desired size and I could call the Measure and Arrange methods on it.

Comment: I think you mean NaN = (double) 0.0 / (double) 0.0;

Comment: @DuckMaestro - Not based on .NET Reflector, no.

Comment: @CodeNaked I think .Net Reflector must be wrong then. Visual Studio "from metadata" view shows NaN = 0.0 / 0.0. This is also consistent with IEEE rules on divide by zero. 1.0 / 0.0 is supposed to be +Inf.

Comment: @DuckMaestro - Yeah, it does look like `PositiveInfinity` is defined as `(double)1.0/(double)0.0`. I'll update my answer.